# Keep alive with idle timeout on server

Tags: netty

I have an idle timeout handler on my netty server.

At the same time my client is sending me keep alives (he has enabled keep alive option on his netty client).

it seams that my idle timeout handler is on an application level, so the keep alive isn't keeping the connection alive.

Any standard way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take away the idle timeout handler.  Why do you have it there if you don't want it to trigger?  If the connection is broken then the TCP keep Alice's should stop and the connection would close without your handler wouldn't it?

If you want the idle timeout for when data is sent then use a flag to indicate if you are in the middle of a request response exchange and ignore all timeout events that are outside of such a request processing state.